# Create multiple stored procedure by running Postgresql script

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I wanted to execute a Postgresql scripts file in my vm containing 3 stored procedure. But only the first one gets executed. Any workaround for this? Scripts file:

```
alter table ex add column if not exists json_column jsonb;  
alter table im add column if not exists json_column jsonb;
alter table imag add column if not exists json_column jsonb;
create or replace procedure update_ex(     //first stored procedure
   js jsonb,
   id bigint
) 
language plpgsql 
as $$
begin
    update ex set json_column = js where ex_id=id;
end;$$  // error: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "create"
create or replace procedure update_im(   //second stored procedure
   js jsonb,
   id bigint
) 
language plpgsql 
as $$
begin
    update im set json_column = js where im_set_id=id;
end;$$
create or replace procedure update_imag(
   js jsonb,
   id bigint
) 
language plpgsql 
as $$
begin
    update imag set json_column = js where imag_id=id;
end;$$
```

Comment: You forgot the semicolons that end the statements.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe...worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

You missing a ";" at the end.

```
end;$$;
```